# -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' while using insertTimeRange in AVMutableComposition

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avmutablecomposition, avurlasset

Following is my code

```
firstAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_strThumbForegroundVideo] options:nil];

AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

[firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

In logs:

**Value for _strThumbForegroundVideo is :**

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/80C71B40-87DA-449F-832C-1D27722727D8/tmp/90219F63-073E-4586-A1F6-DD68B627C3D1.mov
```

**Value for firstAsset is :**

```
AVURLAsset: 0x1702362c0, URL = file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/80C71B40-87DA-449F-832C-1D27722727D8/tmp/90219F63-073E-4586-A1F6-DD68B627C3D1.mov
```

**Value of firstTrack is :**

```
AVMutableCompositionTrack: 0x174033b20 trackID = 1, mediaType = vide, editCount = 0
```

**While doing "insertTimeRange" I get this error,**

```
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]; // index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' while using insertTimeRange in AVMutableComposition
```

I am trying to merge 2 videos using tutorial on [this link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios). The only difference is that in this tutorial, they have imported video from Photos and I have been converting recently recorded video's path into AVAsset and then getting the same functionality done. The video I record can be found in gallery and with the same path that I have.

Here, I need video assets anyhow as it is not optional. Hence, Can not use something like

```
NSArray *dataSourceArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]];
[firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration)
                                                                   ofTrack:([dataSourceArray count]>0)?[dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:0]:nil
                                                                    atTime:kCMTimeZero
                                                                     error:nil];
```

The implementation is done in Xcode 8.1

Comment: before inserttimerange you should check whether firstTrack is nil or what?

Comment: You can't add `nil` in `array` or `dictionary`.

Comment: This may be Issue of your `Asset` , it may not be containing video type Media `AVMediaTypeVideo `

Answer (score 1):

Use the Below code , This may work for you

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]  // Don't use URLWithString if any one using .

AVAsset *firstAsset=[AVAsset assetWithURL:videoURL]; // get your asset

AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                            preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration)
                        ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

Please check before you `insertTrack` if your asset is containing That type of media tracks , here i am assuming that My assets contains atleast one video type media track  `AVMediaTypeVideo`    .

if you are not sure than , check how many tracks of containing your assets.
use below code

```
NSArray *videoTracks = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]];
        NSLog(@"videoTracks count => %ld",[videoTracks count]);

        [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration)
                            ofTrack:([videoTracks count]>0)?[videoTracks objectAtIndex:0]:nil
                             atTime:kCMTimeZero
                              error:nil];
```